# Spring Oauth2 authorizarion server validate only token without clientid and secret in /oauth2/introspect

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

As default Oauth2 has build in endpoint to validated the token `/oauth2/introspect`
With a query parameter of `token`,`client_id`,`client_secret`.

But the implementation is to modified the `/oauth2/introspect` to check token only in parameter without client_id and client_secret since the gateway we are going to use to validate the token only without sending client_id and client_secret.

Kindly let me know, if there is sample project that i can check for reference.

```
http://localhost:8080/oauth2/introspect?token=tokenValueHere&client_id=client2&client_secret=secret2
```

maven dependency for Oauth2 authurization server

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```